# jQuery get the text of all elements in a page

Tags: jquery, text, element

I want to get the text of all elements. I am using this code here:

```
$('*').filter(function()
{
    if(($(this).text().lenght>0)&&($(this).text().lenght<100))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}).each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

I have try to show only short text because .text() sometime returns html code but it is not working at all.

Comment: If that's a copy and paste then you've spelt length wrong.

Comment: You're not the first person to make an obvious, yet somehow very well hidden, typo ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's much more simple: `$('body').text()` gives you the whole text on the page.

If you need to iterate over all the text nodes, see here: [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Comment: Yes, but I need individual text elements. For example: div with text "hi", div with text "user", etc. I need to have an array with this element's text in the final. That's why i use $('*')

Comment: See the link in my answer how to iterate over all text nodes in a document. It's much more complicated than you'd think.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I have fixed my function and make it a little more complicated to do what I want. I will look through your link too.

Answer (score 1):

There is spelling mistake of `length` it should be

```
$('*').filter(function()
{
    if(($(this).text().length>0)&&($(this).text().length<100))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}).each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

cant check if this works atm, but something like this should be what you are after, might need some modifications to filter out scripts and stuff.

```
$('body').children().each(function(index) {
     yourarray[index] = $(this).text();
});
```

EDIT: Tried it out and realised it only takes the first children, not grandchildren and also includes alot of whitespace and stuff aswell, I don't have time to code the entire function for you, but here is a good start atleast. .find('*') fetches all elements inside the document.

```
$("body").find('*').each(function (index) {
    //checks that the text isnt empty, no need to store that.
    if ($(this).text() != '') {
        //stores the elements text inside a temp variable, 
        //trims it from whitespaces and console.logs the results.
        temp = $(this).text();
        yourarray[index] = $.trim(temp);
        console.log(index+': '+yourarray[index]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$("body").find().each(function () {
    if ($(this).text != undefined) {
        ...
    }
}
```