# Get text value from parsed html

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch text from other site I am trying to scrape the text from the site using https://multiverso.me/AllOrigins.

This site get all the content of page in string format. For example I am trying to get data from URL: [TOI link](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/asian-games/such-a-long-walk-from-living-in-cowshed-to-asiad-medallist/articleshow/65361646.cms). I am using this code:

```
 $.getJSON('http://allorigins.me/get?url=https%3A//timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/asian-games/such-a-long-walk-from-living-in-cowshed-to-asiad-medallist/articleshow/65361646.cms&callback=?', function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

The return value is:

```
 {contents: "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html xmlns:xslthelper="com.times.u…deoSwitch" type="hidden" value="1"></body></html>", status: {…}}
```

It is giving me the result as a string. But I want just text. I've tried the following:

```
  $.getJSON('http://allorigins.me/get?url=https%3A//timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/asian-games/such-a-long-walk-from-living-in-cowshed-to-asiad-medallist/articleshow/65361646.cms&callback=?', function(data){
  // $('#output').html(data.contents);
console.log(data);
var str = data.contents;
html = $.parseHTML(str)
console.log($(html).find('h2').text());

});
```

This is returning only one h2 tag but I want to fetch all text on the site.

When I am using the body tag I am getting nothing returned. In this question [jQuery get the text of all elements in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533860/jquery-get-the-text-of-all-elements-in-a-page)

I can see accepted answer is saying I should use:

```
 $('body').text()
```

Is there any way I can fetch all text from a site, just text not javascript or anything else.

For example have a look at this : [Demo Of fetching text from site](https://www.lexalytics.com/demo)

In this demo you can see when I paste the url I can get all text

Comment: Whats wrong with `$('body').text()` That the site does not have a body tag?

Comment: In my case where do I put this $('body').text()  html variable contains all html thing. I have tried: